# wsgi_mod is just showing my .py code instead of running it

Tags: python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I am in a python class and we are currently working with servers, with apache and wsgi_mod. When I start it, the apache shows the code but nothing else, it doesn't execute and it doesn't show errors, it only shows the code.

Indeed I had a lot of problems when I installed the mod, but now I don't know what the problem is...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qubqt.png)